# C++ - Get my IP address from socket on windows.(without boost)

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, winsock

I want to get my IP address by a fake UDP socket. also I do not want to use boost.

```
udp_socket(io_service, udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(""), port))
udp_socket.local_endpoint().address()
```

Is possible I use from winsock2? or other standard lib?

Comment: It might be, but consider that you can have multiple physical and virtual adapters and more than 1 IP address bound to each one.  Which one is __your__ IP address ? Also add IPv6.

Comment: There are better ways to get local IPs than from a socket. You can query the OS directly by using [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersinfo) or [`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getadaptersaddresses)